# How to quickly find the object files another object tile needs to be present at link time?

Tags: linux, compilation, wget, ld, elf

I have compiled the sources of wget, here is the ftp server https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/ to link my own program to one of the object files that I obtained after I compiled the project. But running `nm -u` on the desired file (to be specific `src/http.o`) gives me a whole lot of names that need to be resolved at link-time.

Question #1

Is there a tool to find which other object files are needed to be present for linker to resolve all the symbols? Manually testing every possible combination of object files does not even seem reasonable.

Question #2

When I try to link my program with every possible object file obtained from compiling the project I meet the following error - `multiple definition`. Does it imply that in general I need to select only a meaningful subset of the object files that I get after compiling some project and then building my executable with them?

Comment: If the maintainers of the code intended for you to link in their code then they would provide a library to link with. If that isn't their intention and you still want to use specific parts of their code then unfortunately you will need to spend the time to understand the structure and dependencies inside the code. There could be tools to work out such dependencies but probably the best approach is to add one object at a time as you discover missing symbols.

Comment: Q1 - tool searching is offtopic for stackoverflow. Q2 - Without an [MCVE], it's hard to tell. You would have to tell us how exactly do you "link" your program, with what exactly and in what order and how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a tool to find which other object files are needed to be present for linker to resolve all the symbols?

No. Constructing such a tool would not be difficult (you want to find connected components in the dependency graph), but the problem is not common.

> Manually testing every possible combination of object files does not even seem reasonable.

It looks like `wget` consists of about 100 source files. Using all possible permutations, you would only have to try your link `100!` times, which is indeed a bit too many combinations to try.

As @kaylum commented, the developers didn't intend `wget` as a reusable library, so there is no guarantee that there is a solution even if you do try every possible combination.

Also note that linking in `wget` sources imposes licence restrictions on your final program (you would have to release it under GPLv3).

> When I try to link my program with every possible object file obtained from compiling the project I meet the following error - multiple definition.

That is *expected*: both your own program and `wget/src/main.c` define the `main` function.

> Does it imply that in general I need to select only a meaningful subset of the object files that I get after compiling some project and then building my executable with them?

Yes. And *in general* there is no guarantee that a subset satisfying your requirements even exists.

Comment: I really like your answer, but when I try to link only the object files obtained after running make from project root directory, I still have both multiple definition and undefined reference kind of errors; maybe, indeed, if I examine the generated Makefile, I will see that they are linked not altogether, but in some sensible way certain object files are linked to each other... Anyway, thanks for a good answer, together with @kaylum you made it clear to me.